# Pedir registros que coinciden con un intervalo de tiempo en MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

Tengo una tabla donde realizo un registro cada minuto. La columna donde guardo la hora de cada inserción es de tipo *TIME*. Quiero realizar una consulta que me seleccione los registros que con un intervalo de 2 minutos.

Es decir que me muestre algo similar a esto:

**Columna** 01:00:00, 01:02:00, 01:04:00, 01:06:00, 01:08:00, 01:10:00, 01:12:00, etc ....

La columna de mi tabla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tu respuesta a que quieres algo por un intervalo?, puedes mostrar un ejemplo de que es lo que quiere  que te devuelva el sql?

Comment: user: ¿podrías proporcionar un [mcve]? No queda claro si quieres extraer aquellos registros cuyo minuto sea par.

Answer (score 3):

Sin saber mucho mas sobre tu tabla, capaz alguna locura asi te sirve:

```
select * from tabla where mod(MINUTE(mkm),2) = 0
```

Eso obtiene el minuto del tiempo, y busca el resto contra 2, que si da cero quiere decir que es multiplo de 2.. o sea cada 2 minutos... si quisieras que fuera cada dos minutos impar, solo deberias hacer:

```
 select * from tabla where mod(MINUTE(mkm),2) = 1
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, me sirvio de maravilla, era justo lo que nesecitaba, saludos.